# How to fire click event of a div contained in a ul

Tags: jquery, events

Im trying to get an item in my cart deleted once a user clicks on the delete icon of the item on my dropdown list but it dosnt seem to work. Anyone with an idea, i'll appreciate. Below is my code

```js
$('#delcarts > li .removecart').on('click', function () {
    var pid = $(this).attr('removecartid');
    var conf = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete item? "+pid);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="delcarts">
 <li class="box-li-cart">
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3 box-cart-book"><img src="'.$book_image.'"/></div>
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-8 minicart-data">
            <p class="mc-name">'.$book_title.'</p>
            <p>'.$qty.' X '.$cursymb.' '.$book_price.'</p>
        </div>
    <div removecartid="'.$bid.'" id="removecart" class="btn-remove-prod removecart"><a>[X]<i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I added jquery to your snippet so that it runs, also added `[x]` for the button so there's something to click without font-awesome.  Snippet appears to work as intended.

Comment: "doesn't seem to work" - can you elaborate?  Do you get the alert but nothing else happens?  Do you get the alert, but for the wrong pid?

Comment: no, I dont get alert at all

Comment: If you're not getting an alert, then it's because your selector is incorrect.  As presented here, it works - therefore your code here is different from your real code.  Are you adding anything dynamically (after the page has loaded)?  Try `$(document).on("click", "#delcarts > li .removecart", function() { alert("click"); });` if that works have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: I generated the HTML dynamically

Comment: Then this is duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Answer (score 0):

- You need to use `if` for confirm then `.closest('li')` to get the closest `li` then use   `.remove()`
- Don't use attributes like `removecartid =` you can use `data` attribute instead `data-removecartid` and catch it by `.data('removecartid')` or `.attr('data-removecartid')` .. [jQuery Data vs Attr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261619/jquery-data-vs-attr)

```js
$(document).on('click' , '#delcarts > li .removecart' , function () {
    var pid = $(this).attr('data-removecartid');
    var conf = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete item? "+pid);
    if(conf){
      $(this).closest('li').remove();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="delcarts">
 <li class="box-li-cart">
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3 box-cart-book"><img src="'.$book_image.'"/></div>
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-8 minicart-data">
            <p class="mc-name">Book title</p>
            <p>Qty && Book Price</p>
        </div>
    <div data-removecartid="someid" id="removecart" class="btn-remove-prod removecart"><a ><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true">Remove</i></a></div>
</li>
</ul>
```

If you dynamically generate the `li`s you will need [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

```
$(document).on('click' , '#delcarts > li .removecart' , function () {
```

---

**If you're trying to use `onclick=`**

```js
function removecart(el) {  //el here
    var pid = $(el).closest('.removecart').attr('data-removecartid'); // el here
    var conf = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete item? "+pid);
    if(conf){
      $(this).closest('li').remove();
    }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="delcarts">
 <li class="box-li-cart">
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3 box-cart-book"><img src="'.$book_image.'"/></div>
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-8 minicart-data">
            <p class="mc-name">Book title</p>
            <p>Qty && Book Price</p>
        </div>
    <div data-removecartid="SomeId_Here" id="removecart" class="btn-remove-prod removecart">
      <a>
        <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" onclick="removecart(this)">Remove</i>
      </a>
     </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

> <sup>**Note:** By using `onclick=removecart(this)` in `<i>` icon or
>   its parent `<a>` it will remain the same action</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your response..Let me try it out

Comment: @Harryiyke if you don't get an alert .. This is because 1: jquery not included .. 2: you dynamically generate the `li`s .. answer updated

Comment: I have Jquery added already but the issue is that I generated it dynamically like you pointed out. I tried your first script above and yet did not get alert. When I implemented onclick on the DIV, I was getting alert but was not able to retrieve the data from removecartid.

Comment: I'm very grateful. i'll try your update later today.

Comment: Finally, I've resolved my problem using the onclick method as suggested by @Mohamed. I moved my script to the header where the list is generated and that's it. Thanks to you guys. you really helped

Comment: You're totally welcome @Harryiyke .And I'm happy you fixed your PC ;) . Have a great day :-)